# Android: how to display dropdown options on text view focus?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget

I want to implement something similar to the "To:" functionality in the stock Android text message app. When the focus is on the text field, 3 buttons are displayed right below it (recent, contacts, and group).

I've been trying to find out what kind of widget does this. The closest I can think of is to display a pop-up dialog with 3 buttons, but that's not the same. I've also considered a drop down box, but that's not the same either.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: Android 2.2

Comment: I think adding a screen shot might be useful. Also which version of Android are we talking about? :)

Comment: Don't you want to have a "gone" view (like an horizontal linear layout holding those three buttnos) that shows up when the edit text is focused and hides again on unfocus?

Comment: Yes, exactly what Nuno said. Is that a type of widget?

Comment: Ok I think I see what you are saying Nuno. Just hide the buttons when the focus is not on the edit text. Does the layout resize automatically when the buttons are hidden/shown?

Comment: If you do "gone" the container will resize, if you do "invisible" it'll keep the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a layout something like this: an edit text and three buttons: (notice the horizontal layout defined as gone, which means it won't show up.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_layout"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now on the activity have somethign like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teste_editText1);
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_layout);

    edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View paramView, boolean paramBoolean) {
            if (paramBoolean) {//if is focused
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);                    
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks Nuno. I tried to vote up your answer, but it wont let me until I get reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The actual widget used in the Android MMS app (the one that ships with the AOSP) is a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` ([docs link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html)) to show suggestions based on typing.  [Here's a link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/froyo-release/src/com/android/mms/ui/RecipientsEditor.java) to the source for the subclass they used in that application in Froyo.

Of course, if you are referring to the app on a specific device, it may not be the open source version of the application, but this is still the widget in the SDK that provides a pop-up list with suggestions based on typing.

HTH